# Me sale este error

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\editar.php:27 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\editar.php(27): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\editar.php on line 27.

````
if (!isset($_GET['id'])){
    header('location: ./listado.php');
    exit();
} else {

    $pedido_id = $_GET['id'];
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $tienda = $_GET['tienda'];
    $pago = $_GET['metodo_pago'];
    $idpago = $_GET['identificador_pago'];
    $observaciones = $_GET['observaciones'];

    include_once('conexion.php');

    $sql = "SELECT id, username, email, tienda, metodo_pago, identificador_pago, observaciones FROM tbl_pedidos WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id',$pedido_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':username',$username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email',$email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':tienda',$tienda);
    $stmt->bindParam(':metodo_pago',$pago);
    $stmt->bindParam(':identificador_pago',$idpago);
    $stmt->bindParam(':observaciones',$observaciones);
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultado = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // if ($resultado->rowCount()==0){
    if (count($resultado)==0) {
        echo "no hay ningún pedido con ese ID";
        exit();
    }
?> ```
````

Comment: El mensaje de error está siendo bastante explícito. ¿Cuántas variables enlazadas tenés? ¿Cuántas aparecen en la consulta? Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pon un título más descriptivo.

Comment: Además, ya se han hecho [varias preguntas relacionadas](/search?q=Invalid+parameter+number%3A+number+of+bound+variables+does+not+match+number+of+tokens).